# is $f$ necessarily not injective in a neighbourhood of $p$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R ^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ such that $f\in C^1$. 
Assume there is a point $p\in \mathbb R^3$ such that $rank(Df(p))=2$ (where $Df$ is the differential of $f$)
is $f$ necessarily not injective in a neighbourhood of $p$?
I couldn't think of a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x,y,z) = (x^3, y, z)$ with $p = (0,0,0)$.